# Val_Acc > Training_Acc, yet Val_Loss < Training_Loss – explanation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, classification

I am training a Neural Network with one hidden layer and I get this strange behavior all the time: `Val_Accuracy` is bigger than `Training_Acc`, yet `Val_Loss` is smaller than `Training_Loss`. I do not understand, what this might indicate.

I am doing classification on a 5-class-target, working with `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss and `sparse_categorical_accuracy` as the additional metric. (Yes, my target comes as an integer, it is not one-hotted – "sparse" is correct.)

I tried a lot of tweaking of the hyperparameters; especially LR and node amount.

Because I am using Dropout, I am aware that Testing Accuracy/Loss can be better than Training. The question is about the differing of the two metrics.

```py
opti = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001)
batch = 100
mindelta = 0.0001
lr_red_factor = 0.4
acti = 'relu'
actilast = 'softmax'
kern = 'he_normal'
bias = 'zeros'
droprate = 0.4
target = 5
loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'#'mean_squared_error'
metrics = ['sparse_categorical_accuracy']
nodesperlayer = 30
howmanyhidden = 1

patience = (4000/(nodesperlayer*howmanyhidden))/batch

model = models.Sequential()

first = True
for _ in range(howmanyhidden):
     if first:
          model.add(layers.Dense(nodesperlayer, use_bias=True,
                           kernel_initializer=kern, 
                           bias_initializer=bias,
                           input_dim=feats.columns.shape[0]))
          first=False
     else:
          model.add(layers.Dense(nodesperlayer, use_bias=True,
                           kernel_initializer=kern, 
                           bias_initializer=bias))

     model.add(layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99,
                           epsilon=0.001, center=True,
                           scale=True, beta_initializer='zeros',
                           gamma_initializer='ones', 
                           moving_mean_initializer='zeros',
                           moving_variance_initializer='ones', 
                           beta_regularizer=None,
                           gamma_regularizer=None, 
                           beta_constraint=None,
                           gamma_constraint=None))

     model.add(layers.Activation(acti))

     model.add(layers.Dropout(droprate)) #todo seed?

model.add(layers.Dense(target, activation = actilast))

model.compile(loss=loss, metrics=metrics, optimizer=opti)
```

just one of the many examples to clarify what I mean:

> loss: 1.1345 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.5586 - val_loss: 1.0571 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.6028

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a conceptual misunderstanding, the idea if the loss is that you minimize it during training, because smaller losses are better, but accuracy behaves the other way, higher accuracies are better.

The dynamics of training are such that as the loss decreases, accuracy usually increases, so the behavior you see is correct and completely expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, loss and accuracy are inversely proportional to each other. "Loss" is a measurement for the error that your model makes, while accuracy is a measurement for how good your model performs. Since the validation error/loss is smaller than the training error it makes only sense that the validation accuracy is better than the training accuracy.